# php curl to download multiple photos as zip from facebook not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using curl to fetch photos from Facebook url for authorized user, for each photo I'm adding it to a zip file to allow user to download whole album as zip.

```
 if( !isset($_GET['id']) )
die("No direct access allowed!");
    require 'facebook.php';
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'removed',
'secret' => 'removed',
'cookie' => true,
));

if( !isset($_GET['id']) )
die("No direct access allowed!");
    $params = array();
    if( isset($_GET['offset']) )
        $params['offset'] = $_GET['offset'];
    if( isset($_GET['limit']) )
        $params['limit'] = $_GET['limit'];
    $params['fields'] = 'name,source,images';
    $params = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
    $album_photos = $facebook->api("/{$_GET['id']}/photos?$params");
    if( isset($album_photos['paging']) ) {
        if( isset($album_photos['paging']['next']) ) {
            $next_url = parse_url($album_photos['paging']['next'], PHP_URL_QUERY) . "&id=" . $_GET['id'];
        }
        if( isset($album_photos['paging']['previous']) ) {
            $pre_url = parse_url($album_photos['paging']['previous'], PHP_URL_QUERY) . "&id=" . $_GET['id'];
        }
    }
    $photos = array();
    if(!empty($album_photos['data'])) {
        foreach($album_photos['data'] as $photo) {
            $temp = array();
            $temp['id'] = $photo['id'];
            $temp['name'] = (isset($photo['name'])) ? $photo['name']:'photo_'.$temp['id'];
            $temp['picture'] = $photo['images'][1]['source'];
            $temp['source'] = $photo['source'];
            $photos[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php if(!empty($photos)) { ?>
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();


$tmp_file =tempnam('.','');
$file_opened=$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);


foreach($photos as $photo) {
    $url=$photo['source'];
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $download_file=curl_exec($ch);
    #add it to the zip
    $file_added=$zip->addFile($download_file);
}

    # close zip
    $zip->close();

    # send the file to the browser as a download
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="albums.zip"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp_file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($tmp_file);
    exit;
 } ?>
```

problem: zip->open creates a file, zip->add returns 1 for each file added but the zip size is still 0 and readfile do not prompt for downloading.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($download_file)`? Are you trying to access other people's photos? Facebook might have something to say about that...

Comment: string(some numbers), displayed for each photo. u asking for tht?
And no i'm not accessing anyone's photo user will access their own photos after login, so not illegal I believe if I'm taking users permission.

Comment: Can you add into your question the code for the `$zip->addFile` method?

Comment: $zip->addFile?? isn't it inbuilt for php, here http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: Read the manual for `ZipArchive::addFile` – _what_ does this method expect as first parameter? Well there you go then.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're trying to do this:

```
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $url = $photo['source'];
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $download_file = curl_exec($ch);
    $file_added = $zip->addFile($download_file);
}
```

This will not work because `$dowload_file` is a **string** and not a **filename**. You need to save your cURL parameter to a file, and pass the filename to `$zip->addFile`. If you look at [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php), it's expecting a filename, not a string:

> The path to the file to add.

You need to do something like:

```
$temp_file = './temp_file.txt';
file_put_contents($temp_file, $download_file);
$file_added = $zip->addFile($temp_file);

// Delete after use
unlink($temp_file);
```

Comment: Well what about deleting the files I stored, because it will save them forever on my server? Can u plz elaborate a lil

Comment: It will only ever save one file because the filename is always the same. You'll only ever overwrite it. If you _really_ want to delete it after use, see my updated answer.

Comment: edited code and now I'm getting images but they are not proper. 

is fwrite or file_put_contents creating problem or I'm not getting proper data from curl??

Comment: You are getting a **STRING** from curl. Your zip function needs a **FILENAME**. Which is why I said to save the **STRING** as a **FILE** using file_put_contents, and pass in the **FILENAME** to your zip function.